# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the ORA-01427 error with the following code:

```
update rpt_group a
set a.rpt_category_id = 
case
  when ((select c.control from grpmisc c
 where (c.grp = a.grp)) = '01') then '201'
  when ((select c.control from grpmisc c
 where (c.grp = a.grp)) = '02') then '202'
  when ((select c.control from grpmisc c
 where (c.grp = a.grp)) = '03') then '203'
 else '93'
   end
where rpt_category_id = '93';
```

But when I simply do, say

```
select c.control from grpmisc c, rpt_group a
 where c.grp = a.grp and a.grp = '01'
```

It returns no rows. This is the same for '02' and '03'. So why do I get the "subquery returns more than one row" error?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You're running this test...
`select c.control from grpmisc c, rpt_group a where c.grp = a.grp and a.grp = '01'`

But your sub queries are formed at this...
`select c.control from grpmisc c, rpt_group a where c.grp = a.grp`

If you run the latter of the two queries, I bet you get many records?  This means that either, you're missing the `and a.grp = '01'` from your sub-queries, or you need to limit your results to just one record...

A couple of options could be...

`(select c.control from grpmisc c where c.grp = a.grp group by c.control)`

`(select c.control from grpmisc c where c.grp = a.grp and rownum < 2 order by <blah>)`

Comment: You're right, I did get records with that latter query. I tried doing the options you suggested, but I would get ORA-00001: unique constraint violated...

Comment: A unique constraint violation isn't related to the syntax of the query. It means that the logic you are trying to implement creates duplicates in a unique key. Double check the constraints on the table you are updating, and then the logic you have written. It would seem that the logic needs correcting.

Answer (score 0):

there are at least three places in your code where such error may occure.
you should limit subqueries so they could return only one row. e.g.

```
...
case
  when ((select c.control from grpmisc c
 where (c.grp = a.grp) and rownum < 2) = '01') then '201'
...
```

Comment: Do you mean break the case statements into 3 for each, or use the code as is but appending the "rownum < 2" after each select in the case statement?

Comment: no, your code stays unchanged except subqueries. you should add 'and (rownom < 2) condition to them

Comment: I tried it, and it will run for a while, but then I get ORA-00001: unique constraint violated